# Drawing with CGPath to SVG output

Tags: ios, svg, drawing

I made an paint (drawing screen) with CGPath and CAShapeLayer and now my client want the output image scalable and i found SVG Kit [SVG Kit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) but i don't know how to use this library. I didn't find and example neither in the library examples ! Does anyone know how to use this library for converting CGPath to SVG or can give me an tutorial for ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could start with looking [at this file on GitHub](https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh/blob/master/SVGgh/SVGRenderer/SVGPathGenerator.m). It has a routine to convert a CGPathRef to the d attribute of an SVG Path. I wrote it.

The class method's signature is +(NSString*) svgPathFromCGPath:(CGPathRef)aPath;
[Update: Added code snippet below]

```
#import "SVGPathGenerator.h"
```

...

```
CGMutablePathRef pathToBuild = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToBuild, nil, 10, 10);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(pathToBuild, nil, 20, 0, 30, 40);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathToBuild, nil, 20, 40, 40, 30, 100, 90);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToBuild, nil, 50, 100);

NSString* aDAttribute =  [SVGPathGenerator svgPathFromCGPath:pathToBuild];
NSLog(@"%@",aDAttribute);
```

Outputs:
M10.0 10.0Q20.0 0.0 30.0 40.0C20.0 40.0 40.0 30.0 100.0 90.0L50.0 100.0

Note, the output will not have a close correspondence if you add arcs, as arcs in SVG and arcs in Quartz are described quite differently.

If you want to output it to a simple SVG file, well then you could do something like:

```
 CGRect boundingBox = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(pathToBuild);

NSString* svgAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> \
                         <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\"> \
                         <svg  xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" viewport-fill=\"none\" viewBox=\"%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf\" version=\"1.1\" height=\"%lf\" width=\"%lf\" > \
                         <path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"green\" d=\"%@\" /> \
                         </svg>",
                         boundingBox.origin.x, boundingBox.origin.y, boundingBox.size.width, boundingBox.size.height, boundingBox.size.height, boundingBox.size.width, aDAttribute
                         ];

NSData* utf8Data = [svgAsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[utf8Data writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES];
```

(I have not compiled this code).

Comment: Hi , i appreciate very much your help , if i don't ask for to much can you give me an example how i can use svgPathFromCGPath function ? Thanks and Have a nice day !

Comment: OK, snippet appended.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response but i seen this function , my questions was what is the routine to make an SVG file after i made the CGPath to SVGPath transformation . I really appreciate your effort to help me ! Have a nice day !

Comment: OK, I've added a snipped I threw together to do that too.

Comment: @GlennHowes Hi. I am struggling for a few days to find a way to output an SVG file from a CGPath or a String, or a Bezier ,  using swift. Can you somehow direct me how to achieve it ?

Comment: @Curnelious This very answer says how to do it. Use the svgPathFromCGPath utility in SVGgh to convert a CGPath to a string and then jam it into an SVG file.