# Signature view iOS to svg format

Tags: ios, svg, vector, view, signature

I'm having trouble with signature view on iOS

I have created the signature view and convert it to bitmap
but I have to convert it to SVG too, and I have no idea to do that
I've searched many example, but what I got is just show the svg format to the iOS view, not to convert the view to SVG format
is there any library or example that I can use to do that?

Comment: but why are you convert `SVG` file.

Comment: i need it too print the signature on pdf receipt, so it will be readable on every size, if I use bitmap and stick it on pdf, the signature will be much blurry

Comment: So directly create the PDF rather then convert into `SVG`.

Comment: my server only receive the svg format only. Because on the server side, the svg file will be converted the to png format and put it on jasper report
the receipt and the signature file is in different side, so I'm not allowed to make the receipt on the client side
on the android, I can use https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad to convert it to svg file, is there any library like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting the image into `svg` for that you have bezier path,not need to save into `UIImage`.you need to convert it directly to an `SVG` path string, and then insert that `SVG` path into an SVG document.

[Here is the answer for convert `CGPath` to `SVG`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22213852/200716)

May this helps lot.