# UILabel to SVG/vector?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way/class to take a `UILabel` and turn it into any kind of vector ? for instance `SVG`, or some kind of `bezier path` ?

If it can be done with a `UIImage` (can it ? ) I can simply turn the text first to an image.

A similar effect happens in Illustrator and it's called **tracing** , or for text **"create outlines"** .

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, but I would try to [generate PDF content](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) first, and then find a library that converts PDF to SVG (if that even exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the "Getting Glyph Data" section in Apple's CTFont docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctfont-q6r

A quick search for `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph swift example` should get you practical example code to work with.

Comment: Wow it is doable. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Turns out that's not an SVG output, but  a UIBezierPath . To turn UIBezierPath to SVG is a completely different think which I don't know how to do.

Comment: Is your end goal to generate SVG files? If so, there is plenty of documentation out there for doing that. Here is one place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202741/drawing-with-cgpath-to-svg-output

Comment: Thanks, yes SVG. have seen this one, its an objective c class, dont know how to rewrite it to swift

Comment: There are a number of "Obj-C to Swift" converters out there. If you really can't follow the code, give one of those a try. Ought to at least get you on your way.

Comment: The code is huge, it would take a long time to change this. I was thinking there is a quick solution as bezier is similar to SVG. If you hear let me know :)

Comment: The GitHub repo pointed to in that post is a Framework for iOS. Sounds pretty much like what you're asking for. Unless... can you be a little more clear about what you want to do?

Comment: I want to take a UIBezierPath, and produce an SVG file out of it, using Swift. If you know how to do this using this one I will be really grateful. I just asked about it here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831340/uibezierpath-to-svg

Comment: The person who put together that Framework *outlined exactly how to save a path to a file in SVG format*. What more do you need?

Comment: Search where ? in the guy's library? it's not there. Well if you have the part of code just write it, I am not good at guessing. I'v read all of his readme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147972/discussion-between-donmag-and-curnelious).