# UIBezierPath to SVG

Tags: swift

I'v checked all Google results for this term, and I havn't found a clear answer.
There is the opposite example, there are drawing SVG examples, and there are all sorts of classes for objective-c.

Is there a straight forward way, to turn a `UIBezierPath` into an `SVG` file in `Swift`  ?

The closest I got is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785344/how-to-encode-uibezierpath-to-svg), which I have no clue how to perform step 2.

Comment: Might not be what you want to hear but you could put your objective-c hat on look at the MROGeometry repo and figure out how they do it and build it in Swift.

Comment: I see, Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG

Comment: @boidkan thanks, obviously I'v seen this, they do only the opposite.

Comment: @boidkan sorry, but I don't find how and where are they do it. can you explain more about it?