# Convert UIView to SVG format

Tags: ios, svg

Is it possible to convert contents of UIView to SVG format? (Basically save it to file in SVG format) I know that we can convert it to PDF. But not able to find any clear references on how to convert to SVG format. I have a requirement to convert the current screen to file with SVG format and send it to another system for processing by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm worried that you don't understand what SVG output is.  SVG is a description of a path or paths.  So if your view is just some random view that you hope to get "magicked" over to a bunch of paths, I think you are in trouble.  If it is an image, or some picture that someone drew, look in another direction.

If, however,  you have paths, there are answers like this that show how to convert CGPaths to an SVG view:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22213852/793607

Comment: Thanks. It is going to be a random view. We have a requirement to take a snapshot of the current view in the App and save it in SVG format and send it over to another system for either viewing by the user or printing. We have to probably find some other way to do this.