# Convert CAShapelayers to SVG

Tags: swift, calayer, cashapelayer

Is there any way to convert a `CAShapeLayer` to a SVG image and export  it in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shape layer contains a CGPath. I searched on "convert CGPath to SVG" and found this (rather old) post that demonstrates converting a CGPath to an SVG:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22213852/205185

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. However, I looking an answer for swift.

Comment: So that answer would need to be updated to Swift. Not that difficult a change.

Answer (score 1):

A `CAShapeLayer` is a construct for drawing on the screen.  It handles the efficient display of a shape defined by a `CGPath`, but the `CAShapeLayer` itself is meant to be drawn on the screen.

It would be helpful to think of a single graphic, defined by bezier curves and related drawing primitives that could be drawn using `CAShapeLayers`, or could be represented in SVG.

To the best of my knowledge there is not any functionality, built into the system APIs, for creating images in SVG format.  You would have to turn to a third-party library.  Core Graphics does support PDF as a metafile format (a file in which drawing commands can be recorded) but I don't think Apple supports SVG as a metafile format.